# Access Denied? Wrong user / pass

Tags: java, mysql, cpanel

I'm trying to write a java program to connect to the same MySQL database my website uses. I am using the same login details, minus the hostname ofcourse, but I am getting these errors:

```
SQLException: Access denied for user 'USER'@'HOSTNAME' (using password: YES)
SQLState: 28000
VendorError: 1045
```

I am using the hostname my host provided, and the password and user are the same details I have on my website.

Here is the code snippit:

```
public main() {
        Connection con = null;
        String mysql_hostname   = "HOST";
        String mysql_username   = "USER";
        String mysql_password   = "PASS";
        String mysql_database   = "DB";
        int mysql_port          = 3306;
        initComponents();

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ mysql_hostname +":"+ mysql_port +"/"+ mysql_database +"?user="+ mysql_username +"&password="+ mysql_password);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
```

This is probably to do with some cPanel settings, but I am very new to Java, so asking couldn't hurt...right? :D

Comment: Googling for those two error codes gives a lot of results.

Comment: i did..all it said was the user and pass were wrong, even though they are the same details my websites uses.

Comment: Did you load database Driver?

Comment: Maybe the error is misleading and the access from outside is blocked by a firewall. Have you tried telnet on the database port?

Comment: Andreas, I shall try that shortly. Alex Yes, I have loaded the connector library and have imported them. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I couldn't try telnet, but I did a port checker :P and the default mysql port is open. I'm sure the server is using the default port because I'm not specifying a port on my website and it connects fine. Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On cPanel as I remember when you create a db user there is also a hostname associated with that user default (localhost), If you are running your code on local machine you have to add your IP (public IP) or % in hostname for this db user from cPanel. So mysql will allow connection from your machine.

Note: adding % is risky, make sure you have a strong password.